# Tag markdown in About Me section rendered locally in meta sites

Tags: bug, tags, profile-page, per-site-meta

I just noticed [this profile now](//meta.stackexchange.com/users/190161/johannes-kuhn). Nothing special but he does have a tag in his About Me:

> [image]

I clicked it, fully expecting to land [here](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcl), same way as [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) leads to on Stack Overflow.

But I landed [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcl) instead, the tag page here on Meta, where of course it contains no questions. It also occurs in all other sites.

To top this all, consider his [network profile](//stackexchange.com/users/785560/johannes-kuhn?tab=accounts): clicking the tag there leads to https://stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcl which sends me to search for a panda.

Can the tag point to the original site where the user has first wrote the About Me, or at least removed in the network profile? (or just put the tag name, unclickable)

Comment: I know this has been asked already. Searching for a dup.

Comment: The duplicate one is a feature-request instead of a bug. :)

Comment: @hims056 grr!!!

Comment: Upvoters: I hope you also upvote the dupe. :)