# tagging across SE sites

Tags: discussion, tags, cross-site-tags

Is there a format with which to `[tag:foo]` from one StackExchange site to another?

On my profile, I chose to push changes to all the SE profiles I have, but the tags come over in a rather useless fashion. I can make a [monkey](/questions/tagged/monkey) tag here or on any other site, but it links to an empty page.

Is there a way to `[tag:stackoverflow:foo]` or somesuch, or should I just change all the tags to external links?

Comment: Related maybe dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172841/152859

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Agreed, I am asking the same thing. I looked before posting, but didn't find that question. Should I just close this one?

Comment: Teehee. Now I see you asked the same thing, too, at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208350/230855

Comment: Yeah, I learned about that one the hard way. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's not.

The closest you can get is that there's a consistent URL format.

```
[tag](http://mainURL/questions/tagged/tag)
```